# Let $Z\sim N(0,1)$. Give a clean and rigorous proof that $Z^3$ cannot be normally distributed

Tags: normal-distribution

Just as the title suggests. I simply have no idea how to prove that a random variable is not normally distributed. I'd really appreciate some hint.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will hep you understand how best to form questions and answers. The lingua franca for formulation is [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: You can check directly that $E\exp(tZ^3)$ is not finite if $t\ne 0$.

Comment: As a hint:  Note that $P(Z^3≤1)=P(Z≤1)$ which tells that, were the distribution normal, we'd have $\sigma =1 $.  But $P(Z^3≤2)\neq P(Z≤2)$.

Answer (score 2):

If $Z^3$ were normally distributed, then it would have variance $\mathbf{E}(Z^6) = 15$ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Moments) but this contradicts at once the easy fact $\mathbf{P}(Z^3 \in (-1,1)) = \mathbf{P}(Z \in (-1,1)).$

Comment: Do you mean the variance or the expectation?

Comment: The expectation of $Z^3$ is zero because it is symmetric. Don't make do all the leg work. You should try to do some as well. =)